# Xamarin.Forms UWP custom icon for the secondary ToolBarItems button

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, uwp, uwp-xaml, xamarin.uwp

Is there a way to customize the "3-dot" button, that shows the Secondary ToolBarItem list in Xamarin.Forms UWP app?

It is possible to do so for iOS and Android, using the custom renderers. However, I was not able to locate the corresponding UIElement from the UWP custom renderer class.

Any ideas of how to access the button and change its appearance (particularly, change the icon)?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Derive from [source code](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/b3600a24240c5fd0bc9f90ba7daeea5699dc5728/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.UAP/Platform.cs#L506), Xamarin toolbar will be rendered as `CommandBar` within UWP platform. If you want to edit three dot. the easy way is edit the default UWP `CommandBar` style, find the `MoreButton` button element, and replace FontIcon glyph property value with you want. The following is `CommandBar` segment style that replace the three dot with heart.

```
<Button
x:Name="MoreButton"
Grid.Column="1"
MinHeight="{ThemeResource AppBarThemeCompactHeight}"
Padding="{ThemeResource CommandBarMoreButtonMargin}"
VerticalAlignment="Top"
Control.IsTemplateKeyTipTarget="True"
Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
IsAccessKeyScope="True"
Style="{StaticResource EllipsisButtonRevealStyle}"
Visibility="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=CommandBarTemplateSettings.EffectiveOverflowButtonVisibility}">
  <FontIcon
      x:Name="EllipsisIcon"
      Height="15"
      VerticalAlignment="Top"
      FontFamily="{ThemeResource SymbolThemeFontFamily}"
      FontSize="15"
      Glyph="&#xEB51;" />

</Button>
```

There are many icons that you can customize. You can refer to [Segoe Fluent Icons font](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/style/segoe-fluent-icons-font#pua-e700-e900)

Note: You need to the set the margin of the `FontIcon` to adjust the icon vertically and horizontally centered.

Comment: Didn't have a chance to try it yet, but it looks like the solution. I will post an update here then. Thank you!